# Setting the value of diff for bottom and weight blobs in Python layer in Caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am implementing a new layer in Caffe using the [Python layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/python.html). In the backward function, I see that I need to update the `diff` property of each blob so that the solver can update the parameters accordingly.

I have attempted to do this, but my network is not behaving correctly. I would like to know if this is because of an error in updating the `diff`.

In my case, I have a single `bottom` blob and a single parameter blob, each of size `1`. So, I am doing:

```
bottom[0].diff[...] = top[0].diff[0] * derivative_of_activation_function_with_respect_to_inputs(inputs_to_layer)
self.blobs[0].diff[...] = top[0].diff[0] * derivative_of_activation_function_with_respect_to_parameters(inputs_to_layer)
```

Here, `blobs` is the variable used to denote my parameter blob.

As per my understanding, `top[0].diff[0]` will store the derivative of the cost function with respect to the outputs of the current layer.

1. Is this the correct way of updating my `diff`?
2. While experimenting, I noticed that even if I set the `diff` of the parameter blob to `0`, the parameter was getting updated. What was wrong here? Haven't I effectively set the learning rate for that parameter to `0`?
3. In addition, for a general layer with an arbitrary number of inputs,
   outputs, and parameters, could you please give an example of how
   this would be done?

Thank you.